# RDP forwarding on HP/UX machine

Tags: unix, port-forwarding, rdp, hp-ux

I have a setup that consists of a HPUX machine that acts as a router and has a set of windows machines sitting behind it.

I have given the HPUX box 3 external IP address on our main network so we can connect to those IP via RDP and then forward the traffic to the relevant machines on 3389.

I have tried setting this up using IP Filter but it doesn't appear to work, maybe I am going down the wrong route here, can anyone advise on the best approach?

Comment: Post your config as part of your question. Both the config for your adapters with the IP addresses (obfuscate the public ones), and the IPFilter config.

Answer (score 0):

So the windows boxes behind the HP-UX box have the "internal" ip address of the HP-UX box as their default gateway?